# iOS: Alter UIImage to make it unrecognizable, then reverse to get the original back

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am trying to get a user A to send a uiimage to another user B: the image sent by A should be altered to the point of being unrecognizable, until B pressed a button which reverses the alteration and get the original image.

I found stuff online to encrypt NSData, but it seems to be overkill as I only want a visual alteration of the image that is reversible. Any ideas?

Comment: prob easier to encrypt the data of the image, then on the other side, you show a dummy scrambled image, then when you need to show the real one you just decrypt the data and show it

Comment: OK I can't get any working encryption system to work in swift 3, though. Every project I found on github is riddled with syntax errors that are too complicated for me to fix. Do you have a good resource to recommend?

Comment: nope sorry, prob all the swift libraries are in swift 2 still